# Parent - child application model

Tags: android

Iam building a system with includes couple of applications,
I would like to know if there is a way to design a "main" application which will include **inside** several applications, so in this case i could also share same proccess

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

1)
Application with a couple of [activities](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/app/Activity.html).
In android an Activity is basically a screen.

2)
Create different applications and then from the main one launch an [intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Intent.html).
[Here](http://www.droidnova.com/use-intents-to-start-other-activities,76.html) you have a tutorial of how to do it.

Comment: Multi activity? , what is that? could you be more exact please?

Comment: if we go into option number 2: the problem is that it will open me also new proccess, and i want it all to be in the same proccess.

Comment: coz i want to run a local service, if ill use diffrent proccess then local service wont work, right?

Comment: i was trying to look for it, couldnt find the part where it says diffrent

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [multi-threading](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f8/android-multi-tasking-background-apps-822/) to me.